# Fixed points through a general circle.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, coordinate-systems

The circle $C: x^2 + y^2 + kx + (1+k)y - (k+1)=0$ passes through two fixed points for every real number $k$. Find $(i)$ co-ordinates of these two points and $(ii)$ the minimum value of the radius.

Comment: Yes, sir! How much time do we have for this, please?

Comment: What DonAntonio is not so subtly alluding at is that you shouldn't just paste your exercises here, and should not post your problems in an imperative mode. Furthermore, *especially* for homework questions, you should try and show some effort you've put into trying to actually solve the problem on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

This is an arbitrary circle which passes through the intersection of $x^2+y^2+y-1=0$ & $x+y-1=0$

For the second question :

$$x^2+y^2+kx+(1+k)y-(k+1)=0$$
$$\implies \left(x+\frac k2\right)^2+\left(y+\frac{1+k}2\right)^2=k+1+\frac{k^2}4+\frac{(k+1)^2}4$$

If $r$ is  the radius,  $$r^2=k+1+\frac{k^2}4+\frac{(k+1)^2}4=\frac{4k+4+k^2+(k+1)^2}4=\frac{(2k+3)^2+1}8\ge \frac18$$

Comment: @ChristianBlatter, please find the edited answer